# Add a bottom border in a UIButton with rounded corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

How can I add a right and left border in a UIButton with rounded corners?

This is my button and I want rounded corners in the border too:

[image]

And the source code of my button:

```
- (void)initialise;
    {
        //add border
        [self addBottomBorderWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] andWidth:2];
        [self addRightBorderWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] andWidth:2];

        //round
        self.layer.cornerRadius  = 8.0f;
    }

    - (void)addTopBorderWithColor:(UIColor *)color andWidth:(CGFloat) borderWidth
    {
        CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
        border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor;

        border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, borderWidth);
        [self.layer addSublayer:border];
    }

    - (void)addRightBorderWithColor:(UIColor *)color andWidth:(CGFloat) borderWidth
    {
        CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
        border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor;

        border.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width, 0, borderWidth, self.frame.size.height);
        [self.layer addSublayer:border];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add a single CALayer slightly larger than your button and offsetting it with a negative margin so that top and left border are hidden. Mind that i cannot test it right now, and it may need further adjustments but it should give you the general idea:

```
-(void)initialise;
{
    //add border
    [self addBorderWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] andWidth:2];
    //round
    self.layer.cornerRadius  = 8.0f;
}

- (void)addBorderWithColor:(UIColor *)color andWidth:(CGFloat) borderWidth
{
    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    border.borderColor = color.CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(-borderWidth, -borderWidth, self.frame.size.width+borderWidth, self.frame.size.height+borderWidth);
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    border.cornerRadius = 8.f;
    [self.layer addSublayer:border];
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: how about autolayout ? you need to change CALayer frame in case of rotate device.